# tree rewriting with []

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am trying to rewrite my AST and output semantic warnings.
If i use [] with a lexer rule it accepts but not with a parser rule why ?
I have a parser rule called "var" and i will like to test the value if declared by doing something like this:

```
-> ^(DECLARATION TYPE var[Main.symbols.test_declared($var.text)] expression?);
```

but i get :

```
unexpected token: Main.symbols.test_declared($var.text)
```

is there a way to get around this ?

Most tutorials i have seen only LEXER rules are used, but i can't based on my grammar,e.g IDENTIFIER is a part of var.

Answer (score 1):

In ANTLR 3, the `var[xxx]` syntax means you are passing `xxx` as an argument to the `var` rule. If this is not what you are trying to do, you'll need to clarify exactly what your goals are. Inside a rewrite rule (on the right hand side of the `->` operator), the `var` rule is already completed so arguments are meaningless. You can reference the result with just `var`:

```
-> ^(DECLARATION TYPE var expression?);
```

Comment: I will like to pass the argument to check if var has been declared already in the symbol table and possibly print the output in the tree.It works if i try with a lexer rule "IDENTIFIER" but not with "var". I don't understand why ? is my question correct ?

Comment: This is a code snippet of what i am trying to achieve. But the "VAR" used here is a LEXER rule. Since i am following this example, i have "var" instead which is a parser rule and thus gives errors.

^('=' VAR exp) -> ^('=' VAR[Compile.symbolTable.lookupStaticName($VAR.text)] exp)